# How Pass some parameter to MVC User Control that is not in ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to pass some parameters to my MVC UserControl like ShowTitle(bool) and the ViewData.Model.Row . How I define my usercontrol and pass them to it?
Tanx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the RenderAction HtmlHelper, found in the MVC futures dll available at [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet).  In your main page 
...

You need an action method on the controller with the parameters.  The action then creates a ViewData for the usercontrol. The usercontrol is returned as a view with

```
return View("usercontrolname", model);
```

The .ascx file then uses the model for just the user control.  The resulting HTML is rendered into the calling page.

Comment: Thank you Matthew. Where I can found more document about this solution or a more complete source?

Answer (score 1):

You can define your control as

```
public partial class MyUserControl : System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyUserControlViewData> {
}

public class MyUserControlViewData {
    public IList<MyData> MyData { get; set; }
    public string SomethingElse { get; set; }
}
```

After that you can create an instance of MyUserControlViewData classin your controller, populate with data and pass it to the view. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you. Is that the only way to do it? It seems so unintelligible.